# Making newly created branch to be visible in fisheye interface

Tags: svn, atlassian-fisheye

I have created a new branch from my repository as I am using svn but i also want that newly created branch to be visible in fishheye interface when I open in browser so that I can track the checkin that are happening for that particular branch , could you please advise how to make that newly created branch to be visible in fisheye what setting I need to to do in fisheye so that newly created branch is visible.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can accomplish this by setting up your project's repository in FishEye to point not to 'trunk', but to the folder above it (assuming you're using the standard trunk / branches / tags structure).  Any commits for the project will show up, which may or may not be what you want.

**UPDATE**

It turns out that Fisheye has some 'presets' that you can use.  See https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/FISHEYE/SVN+tag+and+branch+structure.